# pandas: How do I create a dictionary with two columns and add them to an existing dictionary column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

You need to create a dictionary with two columns as shown below and add values to the dictionary in the existing columns.
The two columns may be separated by `,` and multiple values may be added.

How can this be handled to make this possible?

```
   site  url           urls
0  a, b  link1, link2  {e: link3}
1  c, d  link3, link4  {f: link4}

↓

   urls
0  {e: link3, a: link1, b: link2}
1  {f: link4, c: link3, d: link4}
```

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: I tried, but no ideas came to mind other than inefficient methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try `apply` along columns axis:

```
df.apply(lambda r: {**r['urls'], **dict(zip(r['site'].split(', '), r['url'].split(', ')))}, axis=1).to_frame('urls')
```

---

```
                                         urls
0  {'e': 'link3', 'a': 'link1', 'b': 'link2'}
1  {'f': 'link4', 'c': 'link3', 'd': 'link4'}
```

Comment: Getting this error: "TypeError: 'str' object is not a mapping"

Comment: @Drakax The values in column `urls` are supposed to be dictionary make sure you are using dictionary's instead of strings which look like dictionaries.

Comment: I get `TypeError: 'float' object is not a mapping` when urls is nan, is there a way around this?